# Can't create "if statement" inside a test case in Jasmine JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I can't create "if statement" inside my test case by Jasmine JS.

The error is on a wrong locator but I'm pretty sure it's because something wrong

with my syntax and not because a wrong locator.

** The test case, note to the code block of "screen 4" **

```
describe ('Onboarding - English registration', function() {

    beforeEach(function(){
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
     });

    it ('Enter to Home Page', function() {
        homePage();
    });

    it ('Click on the start button  onboarding - screen 1', function() {

        browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        element (by.id('START_BUTTON')).click();
        browser.driver.sleep(2000);
            expect (element(by.binding('industry[0]')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
        browser.driver.sleep(2000);
            captureScreen("onboarding-screen1");
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
    });

    it ('onboarding - screen 2', function() {
        //TO-DO:
        //element.all(by.css('.industry input[type="radio"]')).get(Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)).click()
        //var randIndustry = "industry_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (12 - 0 + 1));
        //browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        //$('.randIndustryr').click();

        element (by.css ("li.ng-scope.icon-laptop > label.ng-binding")).click();
        browser.driver.sleep(1000);
        element (by.xpath("//div[1]/div/main/div[3]/section/div/form/div[1]/section[2]/div/ul/li[4]/label")).click();
        browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        element (by.css('input.btn')).click();
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
            expect (element(by.css('form.ng-pristine.ng-valid')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
            captureScreen("onboarding-screen2");
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
    });

    it ('onboarding - screen 3', function() {
        element (by.xpath("//div[1]/div/main/div[3]/section/div/section/form/div[1]/div[2]/input")).click();
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
        element (by.css("input.btn")).click();
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
            expect (element(by.id('user_email')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
            captureScreen("onboarding-screen3");
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
    });

    it ('onboarding - screen 4', function() {
        var buttonNotPresent = expect (element (by.xpath("//div[@id='root_content']//button[.='Preview on your website']")).isPresent()).toBe(true)

        element(by.id("user_email")).sendKeys("auto" + Math.floor(Math.random()*11111) + "@vcita.com");
        element (by.id("business_name")).sendKeys("automation man");
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
        element (by.className("input.btn btn-account-action btn-xl")).click().then(function (buttonNotPresent) {
                browser.driver.sleep(3000);
            if (buttonNotPresent === false) {
                element(by.id("user_email")).click();
                browser.driver.sleep(1000);
                element(by.xpath("//div[@class='step-content']/section/form/fieldset/div[4]/input")).click();
                captureScreen("onboarding-screen4");
                browser.driver.sleep(3000);
            };
        });

                // else {
                    browser.driver.sleep(3000);
                    expect (element(by.xpath("//div[@id='root_content']//button[.='Preview on your website']")).isPresent()).toBe(true)
                    captureScreen("onboarding-screen4");
                // };
    });

    it ('onboarding - screen 5', function() {
        browser.driver.sleep(10000);
        element (by.xpath("//div[@id='root_content']//button[.='Preview on your website']")).click();
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
            expect (element(by.css('.uber-form-inner-content')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
            captureScreen("onboarding-screen5");
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
    });

    it ('onboarding - screen 6', function() {
        element(by.name("url")).sendKeys("www.mysite.com");
        browser.driver.sleep(1000);
        element(by.xpath("//div[@class='row']/div[2]/input")).click();
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);
            expect (element(by.xpath("//div[@id='livesite_active_engage']/div/div/div[1]")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
            captureScreen("onboarding-screen6");
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
    });

    it ('onboarding - screen 7', function() {
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
        element (by.xpath("//div[@class='btns']//button[.='Done']")).click();
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);
            expect (browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('vcita.com/my/dashboard');
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
            captureScreen("onboarding-screen7");
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
    });
});
```

** The error from the protractor **

```
<failure type="expect" message="Expected false to be true.">
Error: Failed expectation at [object Object].&lt;anonymous&gt; (c:\automation\tests\onboarding.js:59:132) at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:94:14 at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20) at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1755:8) at [object Object].&lt;anonymous&gt; (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12) at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
</failure>
<failure type="expect" message="Expected false to be true.">
Error: Failed expectation at [object Object].&lt;anonymous&gt; (c:\automation\tests\onboarding.js:77:111) at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:94:14 at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20) at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1755:8) at [object Object].&lt;anonymous&gt; (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12) at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
```

Comment: The error looks pretty clear to me: `"Compound class names not permitted"`. You're using multiple class names in one selector. So what's the problem?

Comment: Try the following: `$('input.btn.btn-account-action.btn-xl')` instead of `element (by.className("input.btn btn-account-action btn-xl"))` since this method is used to locate an element by a classname but what you're providing the method is an element type and multiple classnames.

Comment: Thanks Tom! But It still doesn't work.. :/
 I've update the error inside my post. please your help1 10x @TomNijs

Comment: @IdanE In the error message, the locators includes &quot; marks which isn't supposed to be there, did you use single quotes or double quotes? May I suggest you use single quotes? Currently your error only states `Expected false to be true`, this is no syntax error. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: single quotes @TomNijs

Comment: by the way using browser.sleep is very bad practice, you should resolve promises using .then if you have you browser.ignoreSynchronization flag equals true

Comment: The verification should receive true if the element is present and "if" not it should go into the if statement @TomNijs

Comment: OK, It's ok now.. I've change the IF statement to be according to the browser name and to related to the element expect.
Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you could try is lint your code.
I noticed you had some semi-colons missing and ran you code through this online tool:

http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php

It showed you had some semi-colons missing and some extra. Try it for yourself and see if it helps.